# Tensor in coordinate rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ , $I,J$ ideals of $R$ then:

$R/I \otimes_{R} R/J \cong R/(I+J)$.

Let $X$,$Y$ be affine varieties. I want to use this isomorphism to show that $A(X \times Y) \cong A(X) \otimes_{k} A(Y)$.

However using the result I end up with $A(X \times Y) \cong A(X) \otimes_{k[x,y]} A(Y)$? How to get $A(X) \otimes_{k} A(Y)$?

Comment: (1) Do you know what $I(X \times Y)$ is? I don't think that it's just the ideal generated by $I(X)$ and $I(Y)$. (2) I know how to prove this in other ways; do you want to hear about those?

Comment: Yea, this can be done using the universal property of the fiber product and of the tensor product.  The commutative algebra result you cite won't give you what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, a similar result can be used to prove $A(X\times Y)=A(X)\otimes_k A(Y)$. I assume here that the product $X\times Y$ of affine varieties is defined via the Segre embedding.

Let $X\subseteq\mathbb{A}^n$ and $Y\subseteq\mathbb{A}^m$ and let $A(\mathbb{A}^n)=k[\underline{x}]:=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ as well as $A(\mathbb{A}^m)=k[\underline{z}]$ be the respective coordinate rings. Let $I=I(X)$ and $J=I(Y)$. We then define $I':=I\cdot k[\underline{x},\underline{z}]$ and $J':=J\cdot k[\underline{x},\underline{z}]$, the images of $I$ and $J$ in the coordinate ring of $\mathbb{A}^{n+m}$. This means $X\times\mathbb{A}^m=Z(I')$ and $\mathbb{A}^n\times Y=Z(J')$, so $X\times Y=(X\times\mathbb{A}^m)\cap(\mathbb{A}^n\times Y)$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{A}^{n+m}$ with coordinate ring $A(X\times Y)=k[\underline{x},\underline{z}]/\sqrt{I'+J'}$. Now you have to show that this defines the tensor product $k[\underline{x}]/I \otimes_k k[\underline{z}]/J$, which is elementary and probably works very similar to the result you cited.

Comment: Why don't you have to take the radical of $I' + J'$?

Comment: The whole point is that $I'+J'$ is already a radical ideal! This is the main part of the claim, and this is non-trivial. The same question has been asked a couple of times on SE, and answered.

Comment: For example, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294121 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297014.