# Proving $K(G_1 \times G_2) \cong KG_1 \otimes_K KG_2$, as K-algebras

Tags: representation-theory, tensor-products

I've seen a post ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294121/the-vanishing-ideal-i-kx-ya-times-b-is-generated-by-i-kxa-cup)) that the following isomorphism of $K$-algebras holds: $$K[G_1\times G_2] \cong K[G_1] \otimes_K K[G_2].$$ In Curtis and Reiner's Representation Theory of Finite Groups and Associative Algebras, an exercise asks to prove that $$K(G_1 \times G_2) \cong K[G_1] \otimes_K K[G_2].$$

This is probably more a question on notation, but what is $K(G_1 \times G_2)$?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you know what the direct product of groups is?

Comment: Presumably the same thing. Possibly just as vector spaces. You didn't say what exercise.

Comment: @whacka Sorry about that, the exercise is 12.8 (Chapter 12 is on tensor products)