# Is it true that for algebraic sets $V,W$ we have $I(V \times W ) =I(V) + I(W)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is a follow up question to my previous question [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296334/question-on-an-isomorphism-in-the-proof-that-kv-times-w-cong-kv-otimes-k) Let $k$ be a field and $V \subseteq \Bbb{A}^n$ and $W \subseteq \Bbb{A}^m$ be algebraic sets. Then it should be true that $I(V \times W ) = I(V) + I(W)$ where by $I(V)$ here we mean the extension of $I(V)k[x_1,\ldots,x_{m+n}]$. Now I believe I have proven this (see the proof at the bottom of my question) but when I look at Martin's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/294446/38268), it is instead claimed that we  actually have

$$I(V \times W )= \sqrt{I(V) + I(W)},$$

and for $I(V) + I(W)$ to be a radical ideal we need $k$ to be algebraically closed.

> > **My question is:** What's going on here? I believe my claim is true even without the assumption that $k$ is algebraically closed.
> >
> > Here's a proof user Sanchez told me of, which I have simplified:

First it is clear that we always have $I(V) + I(W) \subseteq I(V \times W)$. For the reverse inclusion consider a polynomial $f \in I(V \times W)$. Then we can always write
$$f = \sum_{i=1}^n f_ig_i$$
where $f_i \in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and $g_i \in k[x_{n+1},\ldots,x_{m+n}]$. Now take any $b' \in W$. If for all $i$ we have $g_i(b') = 0$ then since $b'$ is arbitrary, $g_i \in I(W)$ for all $i$. Then $f \in I(W) \subseteq I(V ) + I(w)$ and we are done. Otherwise suppose there exists $b \in W$  and $i$ such that $g_i(b) \neq 0$. Then wlog we may suppose that  $g_1(b) \neq 0$.

Next, $\sum f_ig_i(b) = 0 $ on all of $V$ by assumption of $f \in I(V \times W)$. So $\sum f_i g_i(b) = p$ for some $p \in I(V)$. Now write
$$f_1 = \frac{ p - g_2(b) f_2 + \ldots g_n(b)f_n}{g_1(b)}.$$

Substituting this for $f_1$ in $\sum f_ig_i$, followed by taking things mod $I(V)$ we get an  expression with only $n-1$ terms $\mod{I(V)}$. Continuing this process we will finally get an expression with $0$ terms $\mod{I(V)}$ so that $f \in I(V)$. This shows $I(V \times W) \subseteq I(V) + I(W)$ which completes the proof.

Comment: There is no difference between "variety" (in the sense Martin is using the word) and "algebraic set". This is implicit in the emphasis on reduced rings. If he meant irreducible varieties he would have been talking about integral domains.

Comment: @ZhenLin Ok, so does that mean that my proof is wrong?

Comment: @ZhenLin Ok it seems that what I claim in the question is correct - if $k$ is algebraically closed - according to Martin's answer. But I don't understand where my proof goes wrong...

Comment: I suggest that you add your proof (or the link to your proof) in the other thread. I quite like it, and it is more direct than mine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your proof is correct. At first sight this contradicts with the statements in the [other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294121/the-vanishing-ideal-i-kx-ya-times-b-is-generated-by-i-kxa-cup/294446#294446) thread. Let me clear this confusion. Let $k$ be a field. By $x$ I mean a system of variales $x = x_1,\dotsc,x_n$, similarily and $y=y_1,\dotsc,y_m$.

(A) For radical ideals $I \subseteq k[x], J \subseteq k[y]$ the generated ideal $\langle I,J \rangle \subseteq k[x,y]$ is radical.

(A') The tensor product of reduced $k$-algebras is reduced.

(B) For algebraic subsets $V \subseteq k^n, W \subseteq k^m$ we have $I(V \times W) = \langle I(V) ,I(W) \rangle$ in $k[x,y]$.

Then we have $(A) \Leftrightarrow (A') \Rightarrow (B)$ and $(A')$ holds if $k$ is algebraically closed. This is what I have used to prove that $(B)$ holds in the other thread. But your proof shows that $(B)$ holds in general. Good to know that!

But $(A')$ does not hold in general, as I have explained in the other thread. Namely, let $n=m=1$, $k = \mathbb{F}_p(t^p)$, $I=(x^p-t^p)$ and $J=(y^p-t^p)$. These are even maximal ideals with $k[x]/I \cong \mathbb{F}_p(t) \cong k[y]/J$. But their sum $\langle I,J \rangle = (\mathbf{(x-y)^p},x^p-t^p)$ is not a radical ideal. Note that although $I,J$ are radical ideals, they cannot be written as vanishing ideals for algebraic subsets of $k$, since we have $V(I)=\emptyset$ and $I \neq (1)$ (similarily for $J$).

Finally, let me mention the "correct" framework for classical algebraic geometry over a field $k$ which is not algebraically closed field. One chooses an algebraic closure $\overline{k}$, and defines $V(I) = \{\alpha \in \overline{k}^n : \forall p \in I (p(\alpha)=0)\}$. The vanishing ideal is defined as usual. One gets a Galois connection between ideals of $k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$ and subsets of $\overline{k}^n$, which restricts to a duality between radical ideals of $k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$  and algebraic subsets of $\overline{k}^n$. This is Hilbert's Nullstellensatz for an arbitrary field $k$. The corresponding statement $(B)$ for algebraic subsets of $\overline{k}^n$ and $\overline{k}^m$ therefore turns out to be equivalent to $(A')$, and thus does not holds in general. This is also why I claimed in the other thread that $(B)$ fails when $k$ is not assumed to be algebraically closed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At your request, I have also posted an answer to the other thread (involving Leon's question).